# How to test keypress event in angular directive

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

i have a directive in Angular which prevents using Enter when maxlength of textarea is met

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[abEnter]'
})
export class EnterDirective {
    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
    onKeypress(event) {
        if ((event.target.textLength >= event.target.maxLength) && (event.keyCode === 13)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

not sure how to test it. was trying something like

```
    it('should allow Enter key when maxlength is not met', () => {
            component.textareaValue = 'abc';
            fixture.detectChanges();
            
            const event = createEnterKeyPress();
            element.triggerEventHandler('keypress', event);
            expect(event.preventDefault).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    
        function createEnterKeyPress() {
            return {keyCode: 13, preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy('preventDefault')};
        }
```

but it did not work as expected

element is:

```
element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('textarea'));
```

Comment: What about [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dispatchEvent`:

```js
it('should allow Enter key when maxlength is not met', () => {
    component.textareaValue = 'abc';
    fixture.detectChanges();
            
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {keyCode: 'enter'}))
    expect(event.preventDefault).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note: "keypress" is deprecated. But you can use whatever event-type you want.

Comment: You can't use dispatchEvent on debugElement